# How to refresh entity framework context upon closing form and returning to master form

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework-6

**My problem:**

I'm trying to make master-detail form. With f5 key when in edit mode in my main form I call Zoom() and open a new form where I can add some more stuff related to what my main form datagrid is showing.

When I add some more stuff or delete and save, and close that form and return to my main form. It won't note the changes in that main form. If I close and reopen my main form it will show changes.

Here as an example I deleted g2 and saved, when I return to my main form and try to edit existing item, or even add new item it will still show g2 as existing. However if I open again my second form with f5 I can clearly see that record doesn't exist actually. If I close and reopen my main form the changes will be shown.

[Main form edit mode - pressing f5 from here will cause Zoom() to be called](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEyRH.jpg)

[My second form and items in it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpjYx.jpg)

[Deleted g2 and saved][3]

[g2 is still in main form][4]

[even if i cancel/save and try to add new item][5]

[Upon close and open changes are made][6]

Other links in comments

**So far I have tried:**

Immediately after calling of new form

master.Entry(a).reload,

masterEntities master = new masterEntities(),

resseting the datasource of bindingsource predmetbindingsource.datasource = master.predmets.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();

and .resetcurrentitem()

**Some code:**

**Main form:**

```
private async void Zoom()
    {
        if (nastavniPlanProgramsDataGridView.SelectedCells.Count == 1 && nastavniPlanProgramsDataGridView.SelectedCells[0].ColumnIndex == 0)
            {
                NastavniPlanProgramForm f2 = new NastavniPlanProgramForm();

                if (f2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {


                    predmetBindingSource.DataSource = await master.Predmets.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();

                    Predmet a = (Predmet)f2.Selected;
                    NastavniPlanProgram s = (NastavniPlanProgram)nastavniPlanProgramsBindingSource.Current;
                    s.idPredmet = a.idPredmet;

                }

            }
        }
```

Entity that which I'm changing is called Predmet, it's bindingsource is predmetbindingsource, and my context is called master and is initialized globally on beggining of my main form:

```
 public partial class Studijski_program : Form
{

    masterEntities master = new masterEntities();


    public Studijski_program()
    {         
        InitializeComponent();
```

//blablabla..

In that other form upon closing i'm just doing context.dispose()

Comment: [3]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/wOZcT.jpg
  [4]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/VEwSn.jpg
  [5]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/S2ZQo.jpg
  [6]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/3pxLL.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit hard to read, partly because I suspect that It's not in English, but here are a few observations:

I'm assuming that `masterEntities` is derived from `DbContext`.  `DbContext`s should be transient, and only last for the lifetime of a request.  They shouldn't be around for a very long time.  One of the reasons why we keep them transient, is because they do a bunch of caching, and problems caching can cause symptoms like what you're experiencing.

Try instantiating a new `masterEntities` right before you query it

```
var db = new masterEntities();
predmetBindingSource.DataSource = await db.Predmets.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
```

if that doesn't work, use [The debugger](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79508/Mastering-Debugging-in-Visual-Studio-A-Beginn) to check and see whether or not it's actually a dbContext-related issue.  Make a breakpoint after the line that sets `predmetBindingSource.DataSource`, and make sure that it's actually been set.